# dictionary format without brackets and comma

Tags: dictionary, format

I have the dict:

```
{'Спартак': [2, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'Зенит': [2, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'Локомотив': [2, 2, 0, 0, 6]}
```

i need print format like:

Спартак:2 0 1 1 1

i try this:

```
for key, value in commands_dict.items():
print("{0}:{1}".format(key, value))
```

and this return
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btiyt.png), but that's not what I need

thank you for you answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```py
for key, value in commands_dict.items():
    print("{0}:{1}".format(key, ",".join(map(str,value))))
```

Note:

- `map` converts each integer to string
- `join` concatenates the strings with comma as the delimiter

Comment: big thank you! but i have error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @Kirysha can you show the full code?

Comment: sure,
    commands_dict = {}
    str = data.split(sep = ';')
    x = 4
    str = [str[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(str), x)]
    for i in str:
        commands_dict.setdefault(i[0])
        commands_dict.setdefault(i[2])
    print(commands_dict)
    lst = data.split(sep = ';')
    print(lst)
    for i in commands_dict.keys():
        commands_dict[i] = [lst.count(i), 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: don't name your variable `str`

Comment: i found solution, thank you!
for key, value in commands_dict.items():
  print (key,end=':')
  print (*value)